# primeNg icons does not work in angular 13

Tags: angular, primeng, angular13

i am going to use primeNg icons in my angular 13 project.i added all css references in angular.json but i cant use icons yet

[image]

and this is my code

[image]

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Try using `i` rather than `span`.